# Android to Wamp Server Connection using Android Studio and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm newbie here. I want to connect my android app to wampserver database. I found a tutorial on this [link](http://inducesmile.com/android-snippets/android-login-and-registration-with-php-and-mysql/#comment-69), But where should I find my serverUrl in wampserver? It should look like this: `private final String serverUrl = "your path here"` So where do I find `"your path here"`?

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package inducesmile.com.androidloginandregistration;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    protected String enteredUsername;
    private final String serverUrl = "your path here";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_button);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if(enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;

                // request authentication with remote server4
                AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
                asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername,     enteredPassword);

            }
        });

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,         RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new     ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
}
```

I am using WampServer with `user="root"` and `password=""`

Comment: Your question in it's present form does not make much sense. If you have a specific question but what you read in a blog post or site you might want to ask that there as a comment.

Comment: But I have also commented there sir, and no response.. Same problem aroused from other users there... I just want to know where is the serverUrl came from... I dont know the path.. please help me sir..

Comment: If you look very closely you will see that there isn't any reference to serverUrl in the code you have posted.

Comment: sorry sir, i pasted the wrong activity, its in the MainActivity.java sir, take a look at my edited post.. please i really need to know the path, Ive created db on wamp, and i have php files on www directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "path" is probably the URL to your local web server, that is:

`http://your_ip/your_path_to_your_php_script`

Comment: is it the index.php sir?

Comment: sir, i get this error :org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused

Comment: If you are on a network. Run ipconfig to get you ip address.
Use that ip in your android app to access you webserver from your emulator. 
You also need a PHP login script in your webserver to handle the authentication.

Comment: Thanks sir, it solved my problem.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **@e4c5** (for the suggestions) and to **@Laser** for the answer(s).

I solved it!

So for the others who will stumble upon this problem, **check this out**! ^_^

Go to **cmd** >> type `ipconfig` >> then look at **IPv4 Address**...

Then paste it on `private final String serverUrl = "your path here"`

Replace `your path here` with `http://192.168.1.8/android_user_api/index.php`

Thank you guys!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you need to find your IPV4 address of your computer, run command prompt in your computer(go to Windows start button and start typig cmd) and type ipconfig and enter to see your IPV4 address of your computer.

Successfully Running WAMP server on your computer indicates a green icon on system tray, click on that, with a menu pop up click on *put online* item. Wait for few second to process its task.

To test your app for PHP MySQL in your android studio emulator, just enter address as `http:\\IP Address\` followed by path of your PHP file in your code.

For example: `http:\\192.168.1.7\test\example.php`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use 10.0.2.2 as the ip address in my developing android app.