# Do I need to create another database in order to connect android app to wamp server?

Tags: android, sqlite, wampserver

There are something quite unclear for me. I have created a database in `SQLite` where all the data can be inserted and retrieved by using real device. Now I wanted to send all the data to `wampServer`. I found a useful answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414898/5256621).

Will the database or table that have been created in android app will automatically created in `WampServer` if the string path is connected correctly ? Do I need to create another database in `WampServer` and using different code ? Can someone gives me some hints ? I really have no idea on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not directly comparable to client/server SQL database engines such as MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server since SQLite is trying to solve a different problem. SQLite does not compete with client/server databases. SQLite competes with fopen().
If you want to use PhpMyAdmin to make changes to your database, you need to rely on making a database with MYSQL (database supported by WAMP). However, you can use a SQLite implementation on PHP. 
 Pls refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm for possible applications using PHP based sqlite connector.